# Gridview in asp.net C#

Tags: c#

I have two dropdownlist, corresponding to the values,gridview should be displayed,,and below is code for it..But i am not getting What's the problem in it!!

```
protected void ddlstudents_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ddlstudents.SelectedIndex > 0)
    {
        BindData();
    }
}

private void BindData()
{
    try
    {
        SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection("data source=C:\\ITS Database\\its.development.sqlite3");

        string strquery = "select topics.name,course_coverages.progress from topics JOIN course_coverages on topics.id=course_coverages.topic_id where course_coverages.student_id=@studentid AND course_coverages.course_id=@courseid";

        con.Open();
        SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand();
        cmd.connection=con;
        cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = strquery;

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@studentid", ddlstudents.SelectedIndex);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@courseid", ddlcourse.SelectedValue);

        SQLiteDataAdapter ada = new SQLiteDataAdapter(cmd.CommandText, con);

        SQLiteCommandBuilder cbl = new SQLiteCommandBuilder(ada);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        ada.Fill(dt);
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();
        con.Close();
    }

    catch (SQLiteException)
    {

    }
}
```

Any Help Would Be Appreciated!!

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: Gridview is not displaying with data corresponding to the selected value!!

Comment: are you tried debug it?

Comment: yes!! several times!! its showing its bound with gridview!! but not shown in webpage

Comment: your select return value?

Comment: I think problem is with ddlstudents.SelectedIndex

Comment: @AFetter sir,, which value,,didnt get u

Comment: @user3048066 you sql query return correct data in data table?

Comment: I can't see the query execute.

Comment: @VitapRamdevputra!!! i changed to ddlstudent.selectedvalue..still same problem :(

Comment: @AFetter!! u mean executereader query!! sorry if it is stupid quetion!! m new to this!!

Comment: @Grundy sir,, i believe so,, butif it is wrong!! please correct me

Comment: sorry to ask such a stupid question - but is your connection string addressing correct database? o.O

Comment: @VitapRamdevputra,, yes sir,,connection string is correct!!

Answer (score 1):

Learn how to find the problem your self. if the gridview not showing correct data you can **[debug](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/79508/Mastering-Debugging-in-Visual-Studio-2010-A-Beginn)** the application and find where it failed.

you have not given how you bind `ddlstudents` and `ddlcourse` , check the values you get for `ddlstudents.SelectedIndex` and `ddlcourse.SelectedValue` as you expected or not.

if values are correct, you can run the SQL statement on your database with above values and see the results.

If you really need to find the error, remove the `try catch` statement from your code,

If you catch the exception, do something with it. otherwise don't.

Comment: mesa agrees with you on this

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
protected void ddlstudents_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ddlstudents.SelectedIndex > 0)
    {
        BindData();
    }
}

private void BindData()
{
    try
    {
        SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection("data source=C:\\ITS Database\\its.development.sqlite3");

        string strquery = "select topics.name,course_coverages.progress from topics JOIN course_coverages on topics.id=course_coverages.topic_id where course_coverages.student_id=@studentid AND course_coverages.course_id=@courseid";

        con.Open();
        SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand();
        cmd.connection=con;
        cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = strquery;

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@studentid", ddlstudents.SelectedValue);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@courseid", ddlcourse.SelectedValue);

        SQLiteDataAdapter ada = new SQLiteDataAdapter(cmd.CommandText, con);

        SQLiteCommandBuilder cbl = new SQLiteCommandBuilder(ada);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        ada.Fill(dt);
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();
        con.Close();
    }

    catch (SQLiteException)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: sir!! nothing happened,,gridview is not displayed!!

Comment: can u explain clearly what the problem is when u change the index of ddlstudents control, is the control fires post back?

Comment: @Guru sir in postback i used seesion to save the username and in !page.postback i wrote code for binding data in ddlcourse dats it!!is that any thing m missing???

Comment: how, in page load the drop downs do not have values, so it might be parameters exception, did u checked with break point on page load for ddlstudents.SelectedValue and ddlcourse.SelectedValue, if no check it once, if the values are nulls you can modify the code under page load.

Comment: if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {

            ddlcourse.AppendDataBoundItems = true;

            string strquery = "select id,name from courses order by name,id asc";
            cmd = new SQLiteCommand(strquery);
            cmd.Connection = con;

            ddlcourse.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            ddlcourse.DataTextField = "name";
            ddlcourse.DataValueField = "id";
            ddlcourse.DataBind(); } this is the code i used in page load

Comment: every thing seems correct, add a break point on page load and check for error, if it returns any error then post here we will check for that,

Comment: @user3048066 on page load you fill only `ddlcource`?

Comment: @Grundy sir!! yes!! basically wat happens is,,hwen user select course from dropdownlist after that student dropdownlist is loaded!!so is there anything m i missing!!